# Custom query to get data that's not in other table

Tags: sql

I have two tables **orders** and **attendees**. Both tables have a field **email**.

I am trying to write a query that gives me back all emails in attendees that are NOT included in the table order.

In normal words my query would say:
"Select all emails from attendees that are not included in order emails."

I tried the following query, but it doesn't work the way I expected it.

```
SELECT A.email
FROM attendee A
INNER JOIN order B ON A.order_id = B.id 
WHERE A.email NOT B.email
```

Comment: What’s the relationship between the tables, one to one or one to many? Maybe add some sample data

Answer (score 1):

> Select all emails from attendees that are not included in order emails

this is solved with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select a.email
from attendees a
where not exists (
  select 1 from orders
  where email = a.email
)
```

or with a `LEFT JOIN` on the `email` column:

```
select a.email
from attendees a left join orders o 
on a.email = o.email 
where o.email is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You should easily use `LEFT JOIN` and find the unmatches by filtering all the match cases

```
SELECT A.email
FROM attendee A
LEFT JOIN order B 
ON A.order_id = B.id 
WHERE B.email IS NULL
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get any results when executing that query

Comment: Why use IS NULL?

Comment: JoeyCoder - meaning you don't have ant cases of attendees that are NOT included in the table order
@JoakimDanielson to find the cases that are not match between the tables

Comment: I asked to provoke you to think about it but ok I spell it out, IS NULL is not the same as being different or missing. B.email could contain an email address but a different one than in the other table.

Comment: You surely right, but the the question was based on the ID as the KEY so I assumed that the issue wasn't on comparing the emails but find the unmatches in the order ID. The second answer is going on your way. I guess we need @JoeyCoder to clarifying it.

Comment: I found a solution (see my answer). Probably there is more than one way to get my desired query. But the one I posted shows me the results I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Django to generate the Query as I can handle that better. The working result is as follows. Thanks for your help guys.

```
(SELECT "attendee"."email" FROM "attendee" ORDER BY "attendee"."created" DESC) EXCEPT (SELECT "order"."email" FROM "order" ORDER BY "order"."created" DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

check :

```
(select email_is from attendees) minus (select email_id from order );
```